# Is it possible to apply manual retention on a dataset in Palantir Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have an incremental dataset. I want to apply specific retention on it. The platform team told me that the current state of the retention service does not let them easily create and maintain custom retention policies.

Is it possible to manually apply retention? Doing some API call to delete some old transaction?

(In this specific case, I would like to delete all transactions older than 6 months.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the answer in related question: [Does allow_retention flag in incremental decorator manage manual delete transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73233556/does-allow-retention-flag-in-incremental-decorator-manage-manual-delete-transact/73234706), doing manual delete transaction would trigger a snapshot and thus not be efficient. So I don't think it's possible but I'm open to suggestion.