# Does allow_retention flag in incremental decorator manage manual delete transaction?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

In the perspective of applying "custom retention" by doing some manual delete transaction on a dataset ([Is it possible to apply manual retention on a dataset in Palantir Foundry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73233489/is-it-possible-to-apply-manual-retention-on-a-dataset-in-palantir-foundry)),

Is the "allow_retention" option in incremental decorator of the downstream transform enough to avoid triggering a snapshot on them? (Or is it only allowing delete transaction by the retention service?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'allow_retention' option only prevents snapshot transactions when delete transactions are made by the retention service.

Comment: So there is NO way in Foundry to do manual retentions?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "manual retention". If you mean "just go in and run manual delete transactions on whatever you want" - you can absolutely do that. However, this will result in re-snapshotting of the downstream pipeline.

However, you can have the Retention service target specific transactions, if that's what you want. It can be configured in that way.

Comment: I meant retention in incremental datasets without triggering re-snapshotting. Re-snapshotting is pointless if you have TB sized datasets or if for example the source data is deleted already. I have never seen any customer accessible retention service nor any documentation for it - that's why I made the statement above.